# setting console app as startup program sets dll as startup instead of exe

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

I have a simple console app and I am setting it to run on startup, but it sets the startup path as a dll that cant be opened instead of an exe that is the main executable. This happens with both `Application.ExecutablePath` and  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`. How can I solve this and put an exe to the run list to be startup app?

```
/*
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
 rkApp.SetValue("MyApp", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                
*/

RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("MMyApp1", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Set value is always being with a dll, such as `MyApp.dll`. Need to be `MyApp.exe`. Need to solve.

Comment: is this a .net core or .net 5+ project?

Comment: .net core. V 3.1.

Comment: you might want to look at how to build a self contained executable

Answer (score 1):

Get the execution assembly name dynamically. Check if key already doesn't exist and then add the key.

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
if (key != null)
{
    var existed = key.GetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
    if (existed == null)
    {
        key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. ` Console.WriteLine(curAssembly.Location);` is printing `...\MyApp.dll` in console. So it keeps same issue.

Comment: @Rifat is your app producing a valid `.exe` ?

Comment: Yes. I can run from the exe as well. And when I change the .dll to .exe in registry, it can also run after startup.

Comment: @Rifat can you try `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` and let me if this works?

Comment: It printed same result as with `using System.Reflection` does.

Comment: @Rifat maybe problem is somewhere else. Check this fiddle it gives right `.exe` I've tested it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/akPSV6

Comment: Thats correct. I think the problem is somewhere else. My app is set up with `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` hosting. And it gives this .dll all the time for `curAssembly.Location`. I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: I think I should solve it with string operation of `string.Replace` method.

Comment: @Rifat that will solve it temporarily. But you should try to catch the real issue.